# Angular Jest the pipe 'async' could not be found

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, angular-spectator

I have angular 14 with jest version 28 and spectator, when testing component that has async pipe in it like so:

```
<aside class="sidebar" [style.width]="(sidebarCollapseState$ | async) ? '10rem' : '25.5rem'">
  <fmrs-side-menu
    [items]="menuItems"
  ></fmrs-side-menu>
  <p-divider></p-divider>
  <section class="sidebar__widget-container">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </section>
</aside>
```

as you can see **sidebarCollapseState$** is an observable, and I am passing it to html.
when I run test file I get an error like this one:

```
NG0302: The pipe 'async' could not be found in the 'SidebarComponent' component. Verify that it is declared or imported in this module. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0302

      at getPipeDef (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs:22642:15)
      at ɵɵpipe (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs:22598:19)
      at SidebarComponent_Template (ng:/SidebarComponent.js:12:9)
      at executeTemplate (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs:12126:9)
      at renderView (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs:11948:13)
      at renderComponent (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs:13134:5)
      at renderChildComponents (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs:11807:9)
      at renderView (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs:11973:13)
      at ComponentFactory.create (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs:13913:13)
      at initComponent (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/testing.mjs:26267:51)
      at _ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>._ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing-bundle.umd.js:409:30)
      at ProxyZoneSpec.Object.<anonymous>.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing-bundle.umd.js:3830:43)
      at _ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>._ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing-bundle.umd.js:408:56)
      at Object.onInvoke (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs:26274:33)
      at _ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>._ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing-bundle.umd.js:408:56)
      at Zone.Object.<anonymous>.Zone.run (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing-bundle.umd.js:169:47)
      at NgZone.run (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs:26128:28)
      at TestBedImpl.createComponent (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/testing.mjs:26270:41)
      at Function.createComponent (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/testing.mjs:26078:37)
      at createSpectator (node_modules/@ngneat/spectator/fesm2020/ngneat-spectator.mjs:1533:29)
      at node_modules/@ngneat/spectator/fesm2020/ngneat-spectator.mjs:1525:27
      at src/app/layout/components/sidebar/sidebar.component.spec.ts:36:17
      at _ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>._ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing-bundle.umd.js:409:30)
      at ProxyZoneSpec.Object.<anonymous>.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing-bundle.umd.js:3830:43)
      at _ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>._ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing-bundle.umd.js:408:56)
      at Zone.Object.<anonymous>.Zone.run (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing-bundle.umd.js:169:47)
      at Object.wrappedFunc (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing-bundle.umd.js:4330:34)
```

I have no contact with html file in tests, here is the test file:

### sidebar.component.spec.ts

```
describe('SidebarComponent', () => {
  let spectator: Spectator<SidebarComponent>

  const createComponent = createComponentFactory({
    component: SidebarComponent,
    declareComponent: false,
    imports: [
      HttpClientTestingModule,
      FormsModule,
      ReactiveFormsModule,
      RouterTestingModule
    ],
    providers: [
      mockProvider(ReactiveFormsModule),
      mockProvider(AuthService),
      mockProvider(EnvironmentConfigurationService),      
      provideMockStore({ initialState })
    ],
    schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    spectator = createComponent();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(spectator.component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

here are also jest configurations:

### jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  preset: "jest-preset-angular",
  globalSetup: "jest-preset-angular/global-setup",
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "@shared/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/app/shared/$1",
    "@core/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/app/core/$1",
    '^src/(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
  },
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/src/setup-jest.ts"],
  testMatch: ["**/+(*.)+(spec).+(ts|js)?(x)"],
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!.*.mjs$)"
  ],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.(ts|js|html)$": "jest-preset-angular",
  },
  collectCoverage: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    "<rootDir>/src/app/**/*.component.ts",
    "!<rootDir>/src/app/**/*.component.html",
    "<rootDir>/src/app/**/*.service.ts",
    "!<rootDir>/src/app/**/*.pipe.ts",
    "!<rootDir>/src/app/**/*.directive.ts",
    "!<rootDir>/src/app/**/*.module.ts",
    "!<rootDir>/src/app/core/**",
    "!<rootDir>/dist/**",
    "!<rootDir>/src/app/shared/**",
    "!<rootDir>/src/app/auth/**"
  ],
  coverageReporters: ["html", "cobertura", "lcov", "text"],
  reporters: ["jest-junit", "default"],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ["<rootDir>/node_modules/", "<rootDir>/dist/"],
  testRunner: "jest-jasmine2",
};
```

When I remove async pipe from html the error is gone but I need it to be there

Comment: Try to import `CommonModule` in the `createComponentFactory`

Comment: @HarunYilmaz I've tried in but no help from it either. nothing changes

Comment: SidebarComponent is it a standalone component ? If it's true you need to import AsyncPipe or CommonModule (it's include async pipe).

Comment: @Tim No, it is not a standalone component, and I've already imported CommonModule in every way possible and also I've tried importing both CommonModule and AsyncPipe directly in test file but it has zero effect on it what so ever

Comment: Having the same issue, but still no solution found, do you have any updates?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and seems like I found the answers, however I'm not sure why it works like that.

In my case my analogue of your "SidebarComponent" which is called "HeaderComponent" was a part of a sideModule called  "NavigationModule". As soon as I imported the module inside the TestBed everything worked for me. Hope it helps! Just importing CommonModule inside a TestBed wan't enough for some reason.

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        NavigationModule,
        CommonModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        RouterTestingModule,
      ],
      providers: [
        HeaderComponent,
      ]
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeaderComponent);
    headerComponent = fixture.componentInstance;
  });
```

Comment: You just saved me hours of finding this needle in a haystack. I did not import the parent module into my test module. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using NO_ERROR_SCHEMA in spec files and it was hiding specific errors that were the root cause of that error, completly unrelated but it was the reason, once I fixed those errors that async pipe error went away.